# Different ::before on first and additional lines on an anchor

Tags: css

My current project wants to have a decoration in front of some of the anchors (A), so far this is done by using ::before. However, it shows up that some of the links will line-break and then the second and eventual additional lines will align left with the decoration where it's nicer if it aligns with the text on first line.

There's a fiddle which I hope explains what we are trying to achieve. The .fake class is just for demonstration how it should look, it's of course not an attempt to solve it: https://jsfiddle.net/p0jLoyqz/

```
.decorated::before {
    content: ">",
    font-weight: 800
}
```

One solution could be to wrap the anchor in another element and add the decoration to the wrapper, but it would be good to keep down the markup as much as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make the pseudo element `position:absolute;` and position it `left:0;` and give the container a `padding` of `10px` or`15px`

```css
.small-box {
    width: 120px;
    border: 1px solid gray;
    padding-left: 10px;
    position: relative;
}
.small-box a::before {
    content: '>';
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="small-box">
    <a class="fake" href="#">my link that line breaks</a>
</div>
```

Comment: I'll get back to this.